# How do I use alignDaily on POSIX & Date objects?

Tags: r, date

When I call

> alignDaily(dt, include.weekends = FALSE)

I get the message

> Error in xy.coords(x, y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default

`str(dt)` shows it to be a POSIXct object.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `POSIXct` to a `timeDate` function as

> alignDaily(as.timeDate(dt), include.weekends = FALSE)

the reason is that `alignDaily` calls `align`, which has forms for `ANY`, `POSIXct` (inherited from ANY) and `timeDate`.  The `ANY` version (and therefore the POSIXct form) looks like this

```
Function: align (package timeDate)
x="ANY"
function (x, ...) 
{
    .local <- function (x, y, xout, method = "linear", n = 50, 
        rule = 1, f = 0, ties = mean, ...) 
    {
        ans = approx(x = x, y = y, xout = xout, method = method, 
            n = n, rule = rule, f = f, ties = ties, ...)
        ans
    }
    .local(x, ...)
}
```

There's no way to force `alignDaily` to send a `y` parameter.  Work around this by casting your `POSIXct` to a `timeDate`, forcing align to run the `timeDate` method.